# C# Unity: Cannot invoke a public method from an object due to the protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help! Im getting an error!

> Assets/PlayerCollision.cs(12,36): error CS0122:
>   `GameManager.EndGame()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Here is my code for collision detection:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerMovement movement;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo) 
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obsticle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }

}
```

And GameManager class:

```
using UnityEngine; 

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour { 
   public void EndGame() { 
      Debug.Log("Game Over"); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Is the `EndGame` method in `GameManager` marked `private` or `protected`?

Comment: No it is set to public

Comment: Here is my GameManager

Comment: using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

 public void EndGame()
 {
  Debug.Log("Game Over");
 }

}

Comment: Edit your question to add code. Don't post it in comments.

Comment: **I need help** is not a proper question title. The title should describe the problem